# How to ignore a div in Web Driver screenshot comparison

Tags: webdriver-io

Using Web Driver, we compare website screenshots to ensure nothing has changed since the last test run.

However, part of the page is a carousel with dynamic content. In pretty much every comparison, this carousel is flagged as different from the baseline screenshot.

Is there a way we can specify a div (containing the carousel) to ignore in screenshot comparisons?

I've checked [the docs](https://webdriver.io/docs) and there is nothing about this when searching using the search term `ignore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way we can specify a div (containing the carousel) to ignore in screenshot comparisons?

Assuming you are using [saveScreenshot](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/saveScreenshot/), you cannot exclude a child element

As a workaround, you could use [execute](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/execute/) to hide it by altering it's style before snapping your screenshot (setting it's opacity to 0 for example)

```js
//...
browser.execute(() => {
        document.getElementById('.caroussel').style.opacity = 0;
})
```